# Unknown relationships in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I have 2 Objects:

- A Member with a unique pid (Person ID)
- A Group with a unique gid (Group ID)

I have about 750 members which i receive from a server but i want to save them into a CoreData Database. The problem i face however is how to link the members to the group. One member has a 0 to many relationship to Group (it can have no groups at all but it can also be a member of infinite amount of groups) but i do not understand how to represent this in my CoreData database. I tried to create a link by creating an entity which only exists of an ipid-igid and creating many objects of it. But it feels really strange and my knowledge of this subject is very limited.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like a normal many-to-many relationship.  Creating the link entity yourself is a way of doing what many-to-many is doing behind the scenes.  The explicit link is not unusual for cases where you need to store information about the connections...for example, if you had to save the date that each member joined each group.

Comment: But is there a way without creating the explicit link yourself? I could not think of another way and you mentioning the "behind the scenes" implies that there is another way of handling this? Could you explain maybe?

Comment: If you create your two entities, create a relationship in each that points to the other entity, set one as the inverse of the other, and mark each relationship as "To many", you have a many-to-many relationship between entities.  Generate managed object subclasses and those will contain methods such as `addGroupsObject:` and `addMembersObject:`.  Depending on how you actually parse your server data you check whether a matching Group or Member exists and make the connection (or connect them as a post-processing step).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW8